# How to find the column total % or row total % in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am doing the following analysis

```
amount_wise_buckets = df.groupby(['binned_df_pd','P2P_Status'])['Unique User Id'].count().reset_index()
```

I am getting the following- `amount_wise_buckets.head()`

```
binned_df_pd     P2P_Status  Unique User Id
0   (0, 2517]    Broken        187534
1   (0, 2517]    F_P2P         4455
2   (0, 2517]    Kept          76370
3   (2517, 5035] Broken        53667
4   (2517, 5035] F_P2P  2       221
```

I want to know what is the % of Broken, F_P2P, Kept P2P_Status

Expected -

```
Bucket_1  % Broken 
          % F_P2P
          % Kept
```

How do I go about this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do `value_counts`

```
out = df.value_counts(['binned_df_pd','P2P_Status','Unique User Id'],normalize = True).reset_index()
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'value_counts' 
getting this error @BENY

Comment: @coder_bg update your pandas ~ :-)